# Angular - leaflet marker event to open modal component

Tags: angular, leaflet, marker

l use leaflet with angular and i would like to make click  addEventListener on marker for open modal component . But the problem is while i run my code below , the addEventListener is open the modal component without i click on marker .

```
        let m =  new L.Marker([33, 44], {
          icon: new L.DivIcon({
            className: 'my-div-icon',
            html: `
            <div>
           <img src="${f[1].weather_status_icon_ar}"/style="width: 30px;height: 
           30px;">
           </div>`

          })

}).addEventListener('click',this.navigate(this.LocationID)).addTo(this.weather)
```

Modal component

```
    async navigate(LocationID) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: WeatherDetailsPage,
    });

    await modal.present();
  }
```

l want to open modal component manually  via marker click not automatic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected, since you call `this.navigate(this.LocationID)`, which opens a modal, and pass the value **returned** by this function call to `addEventListener`.

I.e. your code is equivalent to:

```
const result = this.navigate(this.LocationID);
....addEventListener('click', result)
```

You shouldn't call this function. You should instead pass to `addEventListener()` a function that would call this function:

```
addEventListener('click', () => this.navigate(this.LocationID))
```